# Как правильно писать слова в сочетании с числительными?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!

Как правильно писать слова "отпуск продолжительностью тридцать один календарный день" или "тридцать один календарных дней"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тридцать один день. Даже если сто пятьдесят тысяч сто восемьдесят один — все равно день)))